# API Platform v1.1.1 & Symfony 3.2.8 composer conflict

Tags: php, api, symfony, composer-php, api-platform.com

I have [Symfony Demo Application](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo) up and running and now I'm trying to [install API Platform as a standalone bundle](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/getting-started#installing-api-platform-core).

I'm using PHP 7.0.10 with latest composer, but my previous test was using PHP 5.6.20.

When I try to add API Platform Core as a dependency, I get the following error message:

```
$ composer require api-platform/core
Using version ^1.1 for api-platform/core
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v3.2.8, required as ^3
.2) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.2.8].
    - api-platform/core v1.1.0 requires phpdocumentor/reflection ^1.0.7 -> satis
fiable by phpdocumentor/reflection[1.0.7].
    - api-platform/core v1.1.1 requires phpdocumentor/reflection ^1.0.7 -> satis
fiable by phpdocumentor/reflection[1.0.7].
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/reflection 1.0.7
    - Installation request for api-platform/core ^1.1 -> satisfiable by api-plat
form/core[v1.1.0, v1.1.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `composer.json` file:

Find:

```
"symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
```

Replace with:

```
"symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
```

...or:

```
"symfony/symfony": "^3.2.*",
```

You'll probably need (want) to run `composer update` first, THEN add your api-platform package with `composer require api-platform/core` so you have all the dependencies properly loaded, but it's not essential.

Answer (score 1):

With PHP 7.x, you should be using `^2.0`, e.g.

```
composer require api-platform/core ^2.0
```

<sup>Note: To workaround PHP 7.x requirements, you can try to add `--ignore-platform-reqs`.</sup>

If you get the error about `minimum-stability`, change it to `beta` in your `composer.json` file.

Source: [Compatibility issue when using composer require with symfony 3.1.4 at GitHub](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/131#issuecomment-247093821).

See: [Installing API Platform Core](https://github.com/api-platform/docs/blob/master/core/getting-started.md#installing-api-platform-core).